# A PCA related problem

Tags: machine-learning, pca, optimization, duality

> Consider the problem of *shape averaging*. In particular, suppose $X_i\ (i = 1,\dots, M$) are the input matrices, $X_i\in \mathbb R^{N\times2}$, with each sampled from corresponding 2D positions of shapes (or handwritten letters). We seek a shape average $V \in \mathbb R^{N\times 2}$; $V^T V = I$, of the $M$ input $X_i$ which minimizes the following optimization problem.
> $$
> \min_{V,A_j}
> \sum_{j=1}^M
> \|X_j-VA_j\|_F^2,\ \text{s.t. } V^TV=I
> $$
> where $A_j \in \mathbb R^{2\times2}$ are arbitrary **nonsingular** matrices. For simplicity, we assume all data $X_i$ are aligned so we do not have a translation term in the problem. An alternative approach is to instead minimize:
> $$
> \min_{V,A_j}
> \sum_{j=1}^M
> \|X_jA_j-V\|_F^2,\ \text{s.t. } V^TV=I
> $$
> where $A_j$ should also be arbitrary **nonsingular** matrices. Derive the solution for two optimizations. How do the solutions differ? You can assume all data matrices $X_j$ has rank $2$.
>
> **Hint:** Refer to the PCA problem. Calculate its dual form and you’ll get the answer.

I have some knowledge of PCA, but don't know its duality, so it doesn't help. Hope someone could solve this problem...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since this is an exercise, please add the 'self-study' tag and describe your progress so far